# Nesting more than two types of quotes in R

Tags: r, syntax, quotes, double-quotes

I would like to know how to accommodate more than two types of quotes in a same row in R. Let´s say that I want to print:

> 'first-quote-type1 "first-quote-type2 "second-quote-type2
>   'sencond-quote-type1

Using one quote in the beginning and one in the end we have:

```
print("'first-quote-type1 "first-quote-type2 "second-quote-type2 'sencond-quote-type1")
```

> Error: unexpected symbol in "print("'first-quote-type1 "first"

I tried to include triple quotes as required in Python in this cases:

```
print(''''first-quote-type1 "first-quote-type2 "second-quote-type2 'sencond-quote-type1''')

print("""'first-quote-type1 "first-quote-type2 "second-quote-type2 'sencond-quote-type1""")
```

However, I also got a similar error. Some idea how to make this syntax work in R?

Comment: I'm curious: why do you want to do this?

Comment: I would like to implement a bash code directly from R using the base function `system()`. I used `print()` here just to make the question more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use a quote within a quote you can escape the quote character with a backslash

`print("the man said \"hello\"")`

However, the print function in R will always escape character.
To not show the escaped character use `cat()` instead

so...

`cat("the man said \"hello\"")` will return 
`the man said "hello"`

Comment: or `print("the man said \"hello\"",quote=FALSE)`, although that will also include an index counter `[1]`